# EXERCISE 4.1.2 of Abstract Algebra Dummit and Foote (3 Ed)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

En la primera parte, Trato de hacer doble inclusión pero en la segunda inclusión llego a que $x^{-1} \in \sigma G_{a} \sigma^{-1}$ en vez de $x$...

Sea $x \in G_{\sigma(a)}$, queremos ver que $x \in \sigma G_{a} \sigma^{-1}$. Como $x \in G_{\sigma(a)}$, $x \cdot \sigma(a) = \sigma(a)$. Esto es igual a $(x \circ \sigma) \cdot a = \sigma \cdot a $. Multiplicamos a ambos lados por la inversa de $(x \circ \sigma)$ así: $[(x \circ \sigma)^{-1} \circ (x \circ \sigma)] \cdot a = ((x \circ \sigma)^{-1} \circ \sigma) \cdot a$; esto es equivalente a $(\sigma^{-1} \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \sigma) \cdot a = (\sigma^{-1} \circ x^{-1} \circ \sigma) \cdot a$; esto es igual a $ a = (\sigma^{-1} \circ x^{-1} \circ \sigma) \cdot a$. Así concluimos que $\sigma^{-1} \circ x^{-1} \circ \sigma$ es alguien el estabilizador de $a$ pues cumple la definición. Ahora, veamos que la operación $\sigma \circ (\sigma^{-1} \circ x^{-1} \circ \sigma) \circ \sigma^{-1}$ es lo mismo que $x$, con esto se verificara que $x \in \sigma G_{a} \sigma^{-1}$. Asociando de otra manera se tiene: $(\sigma \circ \sigma^{-1}) \circ x^{-1} \circ (\sigma \circ \sigma^{-1})$, que es lo mismo que $x^{-1}$.\
Podrian darme una explicación para concluir que $x = x^{-1}$ o una método diferente para proceder...

---

[Translation by AM]
In the first part, I try to do double inclusion, but in the second inclusion I get $x^{-1}\in \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1}$ instead of $x$...

Let $x\in G_{\sigma(a)}$, we want to show that $x\in \sigma G_a\sigma^{-1}$. Since $x\in G_{\sigma(a)}$, $x\cdot\sigma(a)=\sigma(a)$. This is equal to $(x\circ \sigma)\cdot a = \sigma\cdot a$. Multiplying both sides by the inverse of $(x\circ \sigma)$, we have:
$$[(x\circ \sigma)^{-1}\circ (x\circ \sigma)]\cdot a = ((x\circ \sigma)^{-1}\circ \sigma)\cdot a;$$
this is equivalent to $(\sigma^{-1}\circ x^{-1}\circ x\circ \sigma)\cdot a = (\sigma^{-1}\circ x^{-1}\circ \sigma)\cdot a$; this is equal to $a=(\sigma^{-1}\circ x^{-1}\circ\sigma)\cdot a$.

Thus, we conclude that $\sigma^{-1}\circ x^{-1}\circ \sigma$ is someone that stabilizes $a$ since it satisfies the definition. Now we see that the operation $\sigma\circ(\sigma^{-1}\circ x^{-1}\circ \sigma)\circ \sigma^{-1}$ is the same as $x$, and so we verify that $x\in \sigma G_a\sigma^{-1}$.Associating in a different way, we get $(\sigma\circ\sigma^{-1})\circ x^{-1}\circ(\sigma\circ\sigma^{-1})$, which is the same as $x^{-1}$.

Could you give me a reason to conclude that $x=x^{-1}$ or some different method to proceed...

Comment: Generally speaking, you should include enough information for people to know what problem you are talking about. Not everyone has a copy of D&F at their fingertips. 
En general, debes incluir suficiente information para que la gente sepa de que problema estas hablando. No todo mundo tiene una copy de D&F a la mano.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Soy nuevo en la plataforma...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que $\sigma G_a \sigma^{-1}$ es un subgrupo de $G$, tenemos que $x \in \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} \Leftrightarrow x^{-1} \in \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1}$.

---

Since $\sigma G_a \sigma^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$, we have that $x \in \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} \Leftrightarrow x^{-1} \in \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: You probably want the other implication, since he currently has your consequent and wants your antecedent.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks!